# How to fetch 64-bit Integer from firestore using javascript client without losing precision?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Given that Javascript only supports `number` type which is IEEE 754 representation of floating point, how can we fetch a 64-bit `Integer` type from firestore which was stored using an Android app? The max integer that javascript can store accurately is 2^53 - 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to store numbers that Firestore can't store natively, you will have to encode those numbers into some other data type. The most logical type for this is to store them as a string, and convert them back and forth upon reading and writing.

Comment: I will need to update several `double` variables to `string`. Is there a recommended way to do this schema migration? Is it possible for me to write a custom deserializer where I can allow a `double` value to be stored in `string` variable with same name?

Comment: There is no way to hook into the serializer/deserializer of Firestore at the moment, although that would be an interesting [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Created the feature request. Thank you!

Comment: Firestore [_can_ store 64-bit integers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

Comment: This answer is misleading. The OP explicitly stated that they succeeded writing a 64-bit integers to Firestore from the Android/Java API.

Comment: This answer does not address the question. The problem here is not representation of data at the server, but limitation of the representation at JavaScript client API.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore can store Integer (int64) values, but, sadly, Firestore JavaScript API doesn't seem to be able to [represent them without loss of information](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/3aa9b0e8d5c8eeb40496058556aaa305a8277d34/dev/src/serializer.ts#L218).

It's an [intended behaviour](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/872).